# Dreamweaver CS5 opening .CSHTML razor files

Tags: dreamweaver, razor

Is there a way to force Dreamweaver to open .CSHTML files as HTML file in editor, so I can use the code completion and all the other feature on a .CSHTML file

I was only been able to force it to open it in the code editor which doesn't have all the design features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16410.html).

Comment: I've followed the advice in the link for CS6 but razor files still ONLY open in code view for me while the design and split buttons are disabled (even though cshtml isn't listed in the 'open in code view' field).  Anyone aware of another way to force dreamweaver to open razor files in design view?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Could I just recommend that if anyone is trying to open .CSHTML files in Dreamweaver and it is opening in TextEdit(Mac). What I did to solve this issue is to go to Preferences > File Types / Editors.

From here add ' .cshtml' to the "Open in code view" text box(note the space before the period, this is required).

Next I clicked the "+" symbol above "Extensions" list of file types, then added '.cshtml' to this list.

Close and reopen Dreamweaver and you should find that when you try and open a .CSHTML file(particularly opening the file via a 'Remote server' connection).

Daniel.